# A strange behaviour of table view batch operation

Tags: ios, uitableview

Preparation work:

1. Create a new single view project
2. embed the view controller in a navigation controller
3. drag two bar button items onto the navigation bar
4. drag a table view onto the root view, make view controller the data source of the table view

My code is as below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var sec = [["00", "01", "02"],
               ["10", "11", "12"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sec.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sec[section].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = sec[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    @IBAction func deleteUpSection(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        sec[1][0] = "something else"
        sec.removeAtIndex(0)
        let deletedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0),NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)]
        let deletedIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 0)
        let reloadedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)]
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.deleteSections(deletedIndexSet, withRowAnimation: .Right)
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(reloadedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    @IBAction func deleteDownSection(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        sec[0][0] = "something else"
        sec.removeAtIndex(1)
        let deletedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1), NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1), NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1)]
        let deletedIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 1)
        let reloadedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.deleteSections(deletedIndexSet, withRowAnimation: .Right)
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(reloadedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

`deleteDownSection` works as expected, but `deleteUpSection` crashed, they are nearly the same.

Something I have discovered:

- If I remove `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` in `deleteUpSection`, it works as expected, both deletion and update are executed.
- If I remove `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` in `deleteUpSection`, it deletes the upper section successfully.

Any opinion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is failing because you are attempting to reload rows in a section that no longer exists (`NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)`).  You deleted the rows of section 0 and section 0 itself in the prior statements which means there is only one section left (ie. the old section 1 which is now section 0).

I'm guessing when you remove `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` and it works it is because even though you remove the section in the next statement, those rows are still temporarily referenced somewhere so when `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is called it does not fail to find those rows even though its section is deleted.

Comment: How to explain the different results between `deleteUpSection` and `deleteDownSection`? If you are right in the first paragraph, how to explain the same code works just fine in `deleteDownSection`?